# Get resourcestring identifier from implementation area

Tags: delphi, internationalization, resourcestring

I have a unit which has a `resourcestring` in its `implementation` section. How can I get the `resourcestring`'s identifier in another unit?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

implementation

resourcestring
  SampleStr = 'Sample';

end.
```

If it is available in the `interface` section, I can write this:

```
PResStringRec(@SampleStr).Identifier
```

Comment: [According to Allen Bauer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390079/how-resourcestring-identifiers-are-generated-by-delphi-complier): "The compiler generates an identifier for each resource string based on the unit-name and the resource string identifier, so that is always stable even if the value changes." So you might try to determine `PResStringRec(@SampleStr).Identifier` at runtime and use the determined value as constant (if you really cannot modify `Unit2` at all.)

Answer (score 4):

Anything declared in a unit's `implementation` section is **private** to the unit.  It *CANNOT* be accessed directly from another unit.  So, you will have to either:

1. move the `resourcestring` to the `interface` section:

   ```
   unit Unit2;

   interface

   resourcestring
     SampleStr = 'Sample';

   implementation

   end.
   ```

   ```
   uses
     Unit2;

   ID := PResStringRec(@Unit2.SampleStr).Identifier;
   ```
2. leave the `resourcestring` in the `implementation` section, and declare a function in the `interface` section to return the identifier:

   ```
   unit Unit2;

   interface

   function GetSampleStrResID: Integer;

   implementation

   resourcestring
     SampleStr = 'Sample';

   function GetSampleStrResID: Integer;
   begin
     Result := PResStringRec(@SampleStr).Identifier;
   end;

   end.
   ```

   ```
   uses
     Unit2;

   ID := GetSampleStrResID;
   ```

Comment: All there methods require modification of Unit2, that is not desirable. Now i moved a resourcestring to interface section, but resourcestring are stored in file resources and i can get it by identifier (without move to interface section). So i want to find (maybe a hack) method to get these identifier.

Comment: The identifier doesn't exist at run time - it's a compile time symbol. The mapping between the identifier and the resource ID is in the .drc file (which is generated by the compiler).